# How do I generate html form with custom style using xslt and xsd?

Tags: java, xslt, xsd, jaxb

We are designing a loan processing system whose main task is to feed data from forms with more than 400 to 500 fields. Also there are different types of loan each of which may have different fields. We are using JAXB to generate classes from xsd files and are using Spring framework's controllers in order to bind data from view to our server. In the end, the data is saved in xml files.

The main complexity of the project is to ease the tedious task of creating different forms for different loan types. Hence I am looking into the possibility of reusing the .xsd files that we have created to generate classes. Is it possible to reuse the xsd files to create HTML forms? Also we are using JSP in the view side and our designer is designing the forms for us.

I would be really glad if I got any pointers.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but maybe you can have a look at [dynaform](https://github.com/reinra/dynaform). [Related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761837/generate-html-form-from-schematron/41836501) have been asked before on stackoverflow